# Angular2 class name collision

Tags: angular

I am using Angular2 with Typescript.

I have created a class called `Input` and tried to use it in one of the components which uses `Input` annotation. Now when I tried to create an instance of my `Input` class, I got an incorrect instance of `InputMetadata` which is apparently due to the conflict with `Input` imported from '@angular/core':

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';

import { Input } from '../controls/input';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'dynamic-form',
    templateUrl: 'dynamic-form.component.html',
    directives: [DynamicFormInputComponent, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
         let control = new Input({});
         console.log(control);

    }
}
```

Is there a way to alias a class locally e.g. so that my `Input` would be imported as FormInput.. If not, what would be one reasonable solution for this problem without renaming my `Input` class.

Comment: `import { ... as .... }`...........

Comment: I would really avoid using 'reserved names' as names for your own classes. But @peeskillet's comment should help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [aliasing syntax of the `import` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import) for this:

```
import { Input as InputControl } from '../controls/input';

// …
let control = new InputControl({});
```

You probably want to look for making your `Input` class more descriptive though since it’s not really clear if it’s a component, a directive, a (form) control, or something else.